# how to search and replace "-" character with "\0" in a string without sed and tr command in korn shell

Tags: shell

I am working in korn shell, here one variable "date" has some date value. I want to remove "-" character or replace "-" with null, from the date without using sed and tr command.
I tried the following but it is not working:

```
# echo $date
2014-10-16
# replace='\0'
# echo $replace

# echo ${ date//\-/$replace }
/bin/sh: : bad substitution
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr`:

```
date='2014-10-16'
echo "$date" | tr -d '-'
20141016
```

Or you can use `sed`:

```
echo "$date" | sed 's/-//g'
20141016
```

Or use built-in string function:

```
echo "${date//-/}"
20141016
```

Or using a variable:

```
replace=$'\0'
echo "${date//-/$replace}"
20141016
```

Comment: following is also not working:
echo "${date//-/}"
/bin/sh: : bad substitution

Comment: # replace=$'\0'
# echo "${date//-/$replace}"
/bin/sh: : bad substitution

Comment: Why /bin/sh??? You wrote it is **korn shell**. First change your shell to `ksh` by typing `ksh` and then run these commands.

Comment: echo $date
2014-10-16
# echo "${date//-/}"
ksh: : bad substitution
# replace=$'\0'
# echo "${date//-/$replace}"
ksh: : bad substitution

Comment: Don't know what old ksh you may have. Any way you can use `BASH` or `sed` instead?